# SQL query for finding number of columns

Tags: sql

I want to find the number of columns in a table but I want to find them using the LIKE condition.
Is there anyway I can do that?
Thank you very much

Comment: What is your exact SQL engine (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) It appears that you are asking about the [data dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary)

Comment: You want to use `like` on... the column name? The table name??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using sql server, try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM SYS.COLUMNS c 
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON t.object_id = c.object_id 
WHERE t.name like 'TABLE_NAME'
```

Fill in your like condition instead of "TABLE_NAME"